# Java simple print to a USB interface

Tags: java, printing, interface, usb

I have a Java application which print a simple string to a label printer, which is connected on the parallel centronics interface of the PC.

```
try 
{
  PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(“LPT1”));
  printStream.print(“Hello World”);
  printStream.close();
} 
catch (Exception exception) 
{
  System.out.println("printer error");
}
```

This works without problem.

I connected the label printer to the USB interface of the PC and I installed the printer USB driver. The printer is mapped to the USB002. I replaced “LPT1“ by “USB002“. But it doesn’t work.

How can I do a simple printing to the label printer using the USB port, without to enter each time in the printer selection window?

Comment: What kind of endpoint does USB002 represent? A parallel port, serial port or a USB class?

Comment: Operating system: Windows XP. USB002: Virtual printer port for USB. The printer is visible in the printer list of the PC. Status: ready. printStream.print() doesn't work. No error message.